lifetime is borrowed longer than needed
In hold_conn the buffer brick is used in the closet variable. but when i pass it to the function f the borrow is still used for some reason. even though,
functions involved
fn read_header<'a>(brick: &'a [u8]) -> Option<HttpReq<'a>> {
    // get as str anyways
    let hstr = str::from_utf8(brick).ok()?;
    let l: Vec<&str> = hstr.split('\n').collect();
    if l.is_empty() {
        return None;
    }
    let (meth, raw, ver) = fl(l[0])?;
    HttpReq {
        method: meth,
        raw_url: raw,
        http_ver: ver,
        brick: brick,
        header_map: l
            .into_iter()
            .skip(1)
            .filter_map(|x| x.split_once(':')?.pipe(|(k, v)| Some((k, v))))
            .collect(),
    }
    .pipe(move |h| Some(h))
}

// f any err
fn hold_conn<'a>(mut x: net::TcpStream, f: fn(Closet<'a>)) -> Option<()> {
    // initial read, copy body to vec
    let mut brick: [u8; 4096] = [0; 4096];
    x.read(&mut brick).ok()?;
    // ignore if header is larger than 4KB
    let header_end = recursive_find_u32_delim(&brick, HTTP_HEADER_END_DELIMITER)?;
    let closet = Closet {
        req: read_header(&brick[..header_end])?,
    };
    f(closet);
    Some(())
}

defined structs
struct HttpReq<'a> {
    method: &'a str,
    raw_url: &'a str,
    http_ver: &'a str,
    // keep ref valid
    brick: &'a [u8],
    header_map: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
}

struct Closet<'a> {
    req: HttpReq<'a>,
}

error i got
error[E0597]: `brick` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:76:27
   |
69 | fn hold_conn<'a>(mut x: net::TcpStream, f: fn(Closet<'a>)) -> Option<()> {
   |              -- lifetime `'a` defined here
70 |     // initial read, copy body to vec
71 |     let mut brick: [u8; 4096] = [0; 4096];
   |         --------- binding `brick` declared here
...
76 |         req: read_header(&brick[..header_end])?,
   |                           ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
77 |     };
78 |     f(closet);
   |     --------- argument requires that `brick` is borrowed for `'a`
79 |     Some(())
80 | }
   | - `brick` dropped here while still borrowed


I expected that brick will no longer be borrowed after f() is called

No, 'a as it is passed in from outside starts before the body of hold_conn and ends after it. So a function local like brick can never be valid for 'a and hence f can't be called with it. You need a HRTB for<'a> fn(Closet<'a>) instead of a lifetime parameter. There is a Q/A here that explains that in more words though.
